# Reflection - how to?

Tags: java, android, reflection

i want to return a list with all public methods of a android resource, as methodname + argumets, for example open(int cameraId), release(), setDisplayOrientation(int degrees) and so on for the camera.
So i created this method

```
public List<String> getPublicMethods(String api) throws ClassNotFoundException {

    Class clazz = Class.forName("android.hardware.Camera");
    Method[] publicMethods= clazz.getDeclaredMethods();


    List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();

    for (Method met : publicMethods) 
        list.add(met.getName()); 
    return list;
}
```

I can return only a list. How do i change it so it returns the arguments too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider returning a HashMap. That will give you flexibility to return both of the the objects. Method name will be used as Key and then Parameters as a List. Something like

```
Map<String, List<Object>> values = new HashMap<>();


public Map<String, List<Object>> getPublicMethods(String api) throws ClassNotFoundException {

    Map<String, List<Object>> values = new HashMap<>();

    Class clazz = Class.forName("android.hardware.Camera");
    Method[] publicMethods= clazz.getDeclaredMethods();

    List<Object> listArgument = //Get Arguments Here

    for (Method met : publicMethods) 
        values.put(met.getName(), listArgument); 
    return values;
}
```

String for Method Name
List for List of Arguments.